# How to check in servlet that is an user new with session?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am very new to java servlet programming. I have been writing a simple program for practicing java session. There are two `.jsp` file. first one called `index.jsp`, and another one is `selection.jsp`. And there is a servlet called `controller`. At first the `index.jsp` will be called, and user will be submit a input. That will be redirect in servlet `controller`. In that servlet will check whether it is new request or not. If new then it redirect to other page, else will do some other work.

I am checking whether it is new request or not by `session.isNew()` method. But it always says it is not new session. **But, if I disable the browser cookies option then it is working fine.** Now what is my observation is that when in the first I request the `index.jsp` to the container it assign a session along with that request. So when it comes to servlet it treat as a old session. I got this idea from Head first book `Servlet and JSP`.
[image]

Here is my servlet code -

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        user = request.getParameter("user");
        if (user == null) {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
        session.setAttribute("username", user);
        SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
        selectItem.setUser(user);
        response.sendRedirect("selection.jsp");
        session.setAttribute("selectItem", selectItem);

    } else {
        String selectionItem = request.getParameter("selection");
        SelectItem selectItem = (SelectItem) session.getAttribute("selectItem");
        if (selectItem != null) {
            selectItem.add(selectionItem);
            session.setAttribute("selectItem", selectItem);
        }
        response.sendRedirect("selection.jsp");
    }

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
}
```

So, how to determine whether it is a new session or old one? Thank you.

Comment: The question contains the answer: the session is created as soon as index.jsp is executed. So, when a second request is sent to the servlet, the session is not new anymore: it has been created in a previous request. Check if the session is new in the index.jsp, and you'll have true. Or send your first request to your servlet.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your suggestion. Now request first goes to `Controller` then the Controller decide whether it is a new user or not then Controller redirect to jsp page. Is it a really bad practice to check some logical thing like in my case the session is new or not in jsp violating the MVC pattern ?

Comment: Testing if the session is new is useless. What are you trying to achieve? Just get the session (which will create it if it doesn't exist yet), then check if there is a logged in user in the session, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpSession.isNew](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#isNew--) API:

> Returns true if the client does not yet know about the session or if the client chooses not to join the session. For example, if the server used only cookie-based sessions, and the client had disabled the use of cookies, then a session would be new on each request.

So, you're getting `true` because the **client** has cookies disabled. The "new session" check in done in the `else` block of this check:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null) {
    // create new session
    session = request.getSession();
} else {
    // existing session so don't create
}
```

In your code, you don't appear to be creating a new session when a new session is detected. Perhaps that's where you're stumbling.

**Note**: learning the basic Servlet API is a good thing. However, for my professional work I use frameworks which simplify my programming, like [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).